# Индекс находился вне границ массива. C#

Tags: c#

Чувствую, что не правильно где-то реализовал формулу    Decrypt(c<sub>n</sub>) = (Q + c<sub>n</sub> - k<sub>n</sub>) % Q.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string m = textBox1.Text;
            string k = textBox2.Text;
            int nomer;
            int d; 
            string s;
            int j, f; 
            int t = 0;

            char[] massage = m.ToCharArray(); 
            char[] key = k.ToCharArray(); 

            char[] alfavit = { 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я' };



            for (int i = 0; i < massage.Length; i++)

                for (j = 0; j < alfavit.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (massage[i] == alfavit[j]) 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //------------//

                {
                    nomer = j; // Индекс буквы  4

    введите сюда код
                    if (t > key.Length - 1) { t = 0; }


                    for (f = 0; f < alfavit.Length; f++)
                    {
                        if (key[t] == alfavit[f])
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    t++;

                    if (f != 33)
                    {
                        d = nomer - f;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        d = nomer;
                    }

                    if (d > 32)
                    {
                        d = d - 33;
                    }
                    massage[i] = alfavit[d]; 
                }
                s = new string(massage);
                textBox3.Text = s; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: `nomer = j;` вот это что такое **после** цикла?

Comment: Индекс буквы текста

Answer (score 1):

Если цикл

```
 for (j = 0; j < alfavit.Length; j++)
            {
                if (massage[i] == alfavit[j]) 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

завершился штатным образом, то `j` равно `alfavit.Length`, т.е. `alfavit[nomer]` за пределами массива. Вот и причина выхода за границу.

Comment: Не подскажешь, как решить эту проблему? или как бы ты её решил?

Comment: Я бы сразу написал, но мне не вполне понятна логика кода и,собственно, сама задача